# IntelliJ, Angular and SASS, how to use a path with tilde when using SASS standalone?

Tags: intellij-idea, sass

I'm trying to import a SCSS stylesheet from a separate module into IntelliJ Idea, and the watcher does not seem to run. So I thought I'd try to run SASS standalone, but it fails on the tilde-marked paths that is used for the imported module.

Is there any option to make SASS standalone handle the tilde-marked paths that lead to the imported module?

Or, barring that, is here any way to get the error output from IntelliJ:s watcher when it runs SASS? Right now I nothing appears when I run the watcher according to the setup instructions for IntelliJ.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA should show the error: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-file-watchers-in-product.html#b0f498e5

Don't you see it in Run tool window?

Comment: nope, only the "Angular CLI Server" shows up as a tab in that window.

Comment: Found why the watcher did not run: it was looking for *sass files and not *scss files - my bad. Still cannot make the watcher find import paths starting with "~" in the stylesheet, though.

Comment: and found it - just changed "~" to "../node_modules" everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1: I fumbled my watcher setup: it was looking for *sass files while the module I wanted to import contained *scss files.

2: When I changed the "~" paths to "../node_modules/" it all started working.